# Connection refused in Laravel 5.3 and lemp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Sometimes in different places I get the error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in
```

Full Stack trace: https://gist.github.com/mezhevikin/0efb006589016b9e8c97aa54d9100dc5

My .env:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=groupobserver
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I've tried all the solutions [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/pdo-connection-refused-with-laravel-but-not-with-con-new-pdo?page=1) but it did not help.

I use laravel 5.3, Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, nginx/1.10.0, php-fpm 7.0, MariaDB 10.1.20.

Comment: Are you using homestead or Laravel valet?

Comment: This this cloud server, not local server

Comment: Can you connect to mysql using the `mysql -u root -p` on the command line? (or whatever the equivalent MariaDB command is)

Comment: Yes. I can connect.

Comment: My website and database works, the error I get sometimes.

Comment: try using socket to connect your database.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not, check if your database server does not restart by itself. Look into DB server logs.

Comment: Hi. Now i use debian instead ubuntu, and over there no problem.